# Xcode iPhone simulator keyboard press messing with computer audio quality

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

When a keyboard press is done in the simulator, it seems the audio of the simulator takes over, and in turn, makes the audio quality of a youtube video play poorly. The problem is fixed once I quit the simulator and refresh the video.

Any quick fixes for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Xcode, Mac OS, and iOS are you using? What simulator device are you using

Comment: Xcode 11.3, iOS 13.2.2, and macOS Catalina 10.15.3. The problem occurs on all iPhone simulator devices, and I think it is because they are all on iOS 13.2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely keyboard click sounds playing which can push BlueTooth devices into "phone call" mode with a low bit rate codec.

You can avoid that by selecting the internal microphone as the input device for simulators.

**Xcode 11.3.1 & earlier:** Device > Audio Input > Internal Microphone
**Xcode 11.4+:** I/O > Audio Input > Internal Microphone
**Xcode 12+:** By default non-Bluetooth input devices are always preferred if available. If you do want to use BT headphones for input manually select them in I/O > Audio Input.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Just to add, from the simulator go to Hardware > Audio Input > Internal Microphone (Xcode 11.3)